# Can't delete old linux kernel, no disc space

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, upgrade, disk-usage

I want do upgrade my system.

`apt update`

Then:

`apt upgrade -y`

And i got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So i type this:

```
Suggested packages:
  linux-doc-4.9 debian-kernel-handbook
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
48 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 38.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 190 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://security-cdn.debian.org stretch/updates/main amd64 linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64 amd64 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 [38.8 MB]
Fetched 38.8 MB in 7s (4,995 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 142235 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64_4.9.65-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64 (4.9.65-3+deb9u2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64_4.9.65-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-5-amd64' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-5-amd64.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64_4.9.65-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

But got same error. I can't delete old kernels by this command:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'`uname -r`'/q;p' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

Because same error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `df` into your question? If your `/boot` is a tiny filesystem, this problem will recur even if you manually clean stuff up now. We can point you to instructions on how to expand the filesystem size.

Comment: Use `apt autoremove` to remove the old kernels then `apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6QCj.png

can't `apt auto remove`


`apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: Backup your `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file then edit the `status` file , remove the `linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64` with its description then `dpkg --configure -a` then remove the old kernels . Please processed carefully.

Comment: Can't you remove some old kernels manually from /boot?  That should permit installing 4.9.0-5.  But don't remove anything you might still need.